# How to query mysql to select and group by multiple values

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to select and group by all the contentid values of the table below where the match criteria can be several different values.

the contentid values actually represent cars, so I need to select [and group by] all the contentis where the values are 'GMC' and the values are 'sedan' and the value is 'automatic.

i.e. I'm trying to select all the GMC sedans with an automatic transmission.

a query like this fails [obviously]:

```
select * from modx_site_tmplvar_contentvalues WHERE
`value` = 'gmc' and
`value` = 'tacoma'
group by contentid
```

I have no idea how to create a query like that. Any suggestions?

[image: table structure]

Answer (score 2):

You need to "pivot" these data on "tmplvarid", but unfortunately for you MySQL doesn't have a PIVOT statement like other RDBMS. However, you can pivot it yourself by joining in the table multiple times for each variable you care about:

```
SELECT
    contents.contentid,
    transmission.value as transmission,
    type.value as type,
    make.value as make
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT contentid FROM modx_site_tmplvar_contentvalues) AS contents
LEFT JOIN
    modx_site_tmplvar_contentvalues AS transmission
        ON contents.contentid = transmission.contentid
        AND transmission.tmplvarid = 33 -- id for transmission
LEFT JOIN
    modx_site_tmplvar_contentvalues AS make
        ON contents.contentid = make.contentid
        AND make.tmplvarid = 13 -- id for make
LEFT JOIN
    modx_site_tmplvar_contentvalues AS type
        ON contents.contentid = type.contentid
        AND type.tmplvarid = 17 -- id for type
WHERE
    type.value = 'sedan'
    AND make.value = 'GMC'
    AND transmission.value = 'automatic'
```

You can expand this with additional joins for other criteria such as year (id 15) or mileage (id 16).

If you need to use the value only, you could try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    contents.contentid,
    transmission.value as transmission,
    type.value as type,
    make.value as make
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT contentid FROM modx_site_tmplvar_contentvalues) AS contents
INNER JOIN
    modx_site_tmplvar_contentvalues AS transmission
        ON contents.contentid = transmission.contentid
        AND transmission.value = 'automatic'
INNER JOIN
    modx_site_tmplvar_contentvalues AS make
        ON contents.contentid = make.contentid
        AND make.value = 'GMC'
INNER JOIN
    modx_site_tmplvar_contentvalues AS type
        ON contents.contentid = type.contentid
        AND type.value = 'sedan'
```

In any case, make sure you have an index on the value column; these queries are going to get slow.

Comment: this does work, but relies on us knowing the tmplvarid ~ which we won't always know [they come and go]

Comment: Updated to perhaps meet your needs... however, if you can't guarantee that the IDs don't come and go, you're liable to have a bad time.

Answer (score 1):

please try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM modx_site_tmplvar_contentvalues t1 INNER JOIN modx_site_tmplvar_contentvalues t2 ON t1.contentid = t2.content_id
WHERE
  t1.`value` = 'gmc'
  AND t2.`value` = 'tacoma';
```

Comment: This works for joining the table twice, but breaks down when trying to add a third table: INNER JOIN modx_site_tmplvar_contentvalues t3 ON t2.contentid = t3.contentid [also check your aliases and names in the example]

Comment: @SeanKimball Thanks, typo corrected. Could you elaborate on why joining 3 tables break down?

Comment: if I add the 3rd join & AND t3.`value` = '2012'; then I get over 120 results, there are 5 vehicles that should show up. [possibly I'm not using the INNER JOIN correctly?]

Comment: @SeanKimball It could happen normally if there is 1:n relationships. In that case, use `SELECT DISTINCT t1.contentid FROM ....` to get `conentid`. but It's difficult to get other columns with simple query; you need to use sub-query.

Answer (score 0):

This is always false:

> `value` = 'gmc' and
>   `value` = 'tacoma'

Instead, use OR:

> `value` = 'gmc' OR
>   `value` = 'tacoma'

In a condition "and" means "this and this is true at the same time". If you want all foos and all bars, then your condition is "foo OR bar".

**EDIT:**
To select groups **containing** your values, you can write subqueries:

`SELECT DISTINCT name FROM table WHERE name IN (SELECT name FROM table WHERE value='value1') AND name IN (SELECT name FROM table WHERE value='value2')`

Comment: If I use an or then it's possible to select a vehicle [contentid] where it is not a GMC AND a Tacoma

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a `group by`.  This is the most flexible in terms of expressing the conditions.  In MySQL, multiple joins will often perform better:

```
select contentid
from modx_site_tmplvar_contentvalues 
group by contentid
having sum(`value` = 'gmc') > 0 and
       sum(`value` = 'tacoma') > 0;
```